# Getting UnicodeDecodeError when using virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, ascii, virtualenvwrapper

Im trying to create virtual environment with **mkvirtualenv** command and getting this error:

```
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)
```

thanks

Comment: What's your virtualenv called? Does the name have any 'special' characters in it (like é)?

Comment: regular characters only.

Comment: Please post the full command that triggered this exception.

Comment: Also post the full path of the directory you're trying to create a virtualenv in.

Comment: SOLVED!
the directory for environments was with special character. thanks guys!